# Build String in Inspec with Input

Tags: inspec

I want to write an Inspec Profile, in which I can add an input to an existing string.

For example, something like:

```
inspec exec test --input user=abcinst

Input: abcinst
Test:  its('home') { should eq '/db2/{input}' }
```

I didn't find anything yet to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

for inputs you can refer : https://docs.chef.io/inspec/inputs/
you have to use input resource to read the argument passed to

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30027626)